# DB2 Community edition on higher core count server

Tags: database, db2, ibm-cloud

If I run DB2 community edition on a higher core count server will IBM want to charge me for more cores or will the software simply use only 4 cores and 16gb of memory?

Comment: I think you can find better answers to this admin question at dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a dupe from [dba.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [website](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/announcements/ibm-db2-developer-community-edition) or this [site](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=editions-db2-database-product-offerings).

It says that the limit is hard enforced. So you should not have a problem - it will stay limited to that resources.

Answer (score 0):

unlike ORACLE, IBM DB2 manage the licence limit in their code. the database will never use more memory nor more CPU that you licence allow.

you can use it safely :)